# TF 1.10 intra op issue

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

In tensorflow 1.7.0, getting the number of threads in the intra_op pool was possible with the following line of code in C++:

```
context->device()->tensorflow_cpu_worker_threads()->num_threads
```

where context is an object of type OpKernelContext. (because of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7bccde15ce0dd29dce62092a5e9d48ffdc772963/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc#L44).

If the corresponding ConfigProto was set using the following python code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
conf = tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=5, intra_op_parallelism_threads=4)
sess = tf.Session(config=conf)
```

TF 1.7 would output the value of `context->device()->tensorflow_cpu_worker_threads()->num_threads` as 4.

TF 1.10 outputs the value of `context->device()->tensorflow_cpu_worker_threads()->num_threads as 1`, irrespective of the intra_op_parallelism_threads value specified in the ConfigProto.

I was wondering if something changed in the TF upgrade from 1.7.0 to 1.10.0 to cause this piece of code to give a different value or is the number of threads in the threadpool truly 1?

Other relevant information:

- macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6
- Working TF version: 1.7.0
- Breaking TF version: 1.10.0
- Python information: Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6
  2017, 22:29:07) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0
  (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
- Detailed debugging information from
  tensorflow (by setting TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=3 before running the
  python program) says that TF 1.10 is indeed planning to create a
  thread pool of size 4 on this line of [C++ code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7bccde15ce0dd29dce62092a5e9d48ffdc772963/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc#L41). The C++ piece of
  code at the start of this post however outputs value 1.
- This is the
  first and only session being created in the program.

Comment: This should probably be filed as an issue on github